# Custom subdomain per tenant in a multi-tenant b2b Serverless application

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, multi-tenant, serverless, amazon-route53

We are planning a multi-tenant b2b Serverless application. It will have a Cognito pool per tenant but a pooled DynamoDB. The application frontend will be served from a common S3 bucket as well.

When a new user is onboarded, we will provision a user pool for the tenant, identity pool, and role. New records will be added to DDB as well. At the same time, we need to create a custom subdomain for this user that will serve the application from s3.

```
-> I understand I could just add *.example.com but it will intercept garbage subdomains as well that are not connected to any user.
 
-> Also, it seems as if subdomain mapping has to be through CloudFront, which is fine but does CloudFront allow to point any number of subdomains to a distribution/s3 bucket
```

We are using the Serverless framework and it is a serverless application. Can someone please walk me through the process to achieve this? or share any examples.